# Disable Headtracking in the Holographic Remoting Player

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality, hololens-emulator

is it possible to disable headtracking in the Holographic Remoting Player?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

There is no API exposed used to switch the Head Tracking in the Holographic Remoting player app for now. You can take a look at this documentation for more information about existing features: [Writing a custom Holographic Remoting player app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/holographic-remoting-create-player)